# dsPIC33 Simple External Interrupt problem

Tags: pic, microchip, interrupts

This will be laughably easy for someone who has worked with the dsPIC33 and XC16 compiler, but has already cost me a day. Hopefully someone can save me any more wasted time!

Could someone please tell me what I have done wrong here? All I am trying to do is shut off some LED's using an external interrupt.

```
/* Device header files */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

// setup internal clock for 80MHz/40MIPS
// 7.37/2=3.685*43=158.455/2=79.2275
CLKDIVbits.PLLPRE=0;        // PLLPRE (N2) 0=/2
PLLFBD=41;                  // pll multiplier (M) = +2
CLKDIVbits.PLLPOST=0;       // PLLPOST (N1) 0=/2

ANSELE = 0x0000; //set all of port B as Digital
TRISE=0xF0;//configures part of port B as output
LATE=0x0F; // writes data to port B

RPINR0= 0x5400;//set pin 1 as interrupt 1
INTCON2 = 0x0000;   /*Setup INT0, INT1, INT2, interupt on falling edge*/
IFS1bits.INT1IF = 0;    /*Reset INT1 interrupt flag */
IEC1bits.INT1IE = 1;    /*Enable INT1 Interrupt Service Routine */
IPC5bits.INT1IP = 4;    /*set low priority*/

//Main Program
while (1);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

//_INT1Interrupt() is the INT1 interrupt service routine (ISR).
void __attribute__((__interrupt__)) _INT1Interrupt(void);
void __attribute__((__interrupt__, auto_psv)) _INT1Interrupt(void)
{
   LATE=0x00; // writes data to port B
   IFS1bits.INT1IF = 0;    //Clear the INT1 interrupt flag or else
   //the CPU will keep vectoring back to the ISR
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please give us some more info about your problem/errors

Comment: It compiles fine, loads onto the MCU but it does not detect the interrupt when I bring 0x54 high.

Answer (score 1):

I see three missing things.

Missing dspic33 number??

AD1PCFGL = 0xFF, or whatever the datasheet tells you, to turn off the adc on those pins, if necessary.  ANSEL is for choosing adc input, not turning them into digital.

Input pins TRISXbits.TRISX? = 1, to turn your pin into an input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Erik! Ill give that a shot after work.